"git log --oneline" with a blank line as separator
How can I show a blank line between each line on the output of git log --oneline?

You could achieve that by simpling recreating what --oneline is doing in a custom format, and add a newline.
git log --pretty="%C(auto)%h %d %s%n"


try using --pretty option for formatting and to add new line you have to use %n . your command should look something like this :
git log --oneline --pretty=format:"%h %s%n"
in above code:
%h is to show hash commit , %s is to show  commit message and %n is new line.

Coloring is lost in pretty formats without an explicit %C(auto), though. Also, you've forgotten to remove --oneline from the command, which doesn't break anything but is unnecessary here ;-)
